# Performance: Android views generated programmatically vs xml views

Tags: java, android, xml, view, tags

Suppose I want to inflate 50 views inside my fragment/activity/app programmatically.

Compared to xml, does generating views programmatically in Android affect the performance of that particular fragment/activity/app?

If no then would there be any visible effect?
If yes then can you please explain why?

Comment: Android views generated programmatically will be much more efficient than in XML, coz classes in XML are generated via reflection and reflection is slower and than manually creating objects. One more thing the android framework has to scan your XML files first only then it creates theirs respective objects

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The performance is not affected, but each has its pros and cons. Just to name a few:

**XML**

Pros

1. The UI separated from code
2. You can reuse layouts, combine them
3. Faster development, you can check the UI in preview, without rebuilding the app

Cons

1. Its static

**Programatically**

Pros

1. React to runtime conditions

Cons

1. more code (e.g. harder to maintain your code, more potential bugs)

Comment: I'd say performance is definitely affected (positively) when it comes to creating views programmatically too. And it is possible to separate UI from the rest of the code while creating views.